# Implicit differentiation: Differentiating function with respect to integral

Tags: calculus, economics, implicit-differentiation

I am stuck on a simple problem and would highly appreciate your opinion. I have a optimization problem over $x$ with the objective function 
$$F=aG(x,y)+ (1-G(x,y))(1-x)$$
So the first order condition (value function) is given by
$$V=a\frac{\partial G}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial G}{\partial x}(1-x)-G=0$$
I am looking for the partial derivative of $G$ with respect to $y$ at the $y^*$ which satisfies the first order condition. If I mechanically apply the implicit function theorem I get
$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x\partial y}(a-1+x)-\frac{\partial G}{\partial y} \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \ \ \frac{\partial V}{\partial G}=-1 \\ \frac{\partial G}{\partial y}=- \frac{\partial V/\partial y}{\partial V /\partial G} $$
I am, however, unsure if I can simply take the derivative of $V$ with respect to $G$ since $\partial G / \partial x$ is also an implicit function of $G$, right?

I'm helplessly stuck, so if you can point if I need to go into a different direction that would be highly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: What is your goal in this problem?  Since we are not given $G$ explicitly, we cannot solve for the optimal $(x,y)$ explicitly.  Do you want to generate a pair of equations containing $x_{opt}$,$y_{opt}$, and $G(x_{opt},y_{opt})$ that could be used to solve for the optimal point $(x_{opt},y_{opt})$?

Comment: The ultimate goal is to make a statement about the sign of $\partial G / \partial y$. This will depend on the values of $x$ and maybe $y$ which is fine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I feel that this isn't really possible.  $G$, as I understand, is an arbitrary function -- there is no other information besides that $G$ is a function of $x$ and $y$.  The sign of $\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}$ will depend entirely on what the function $G$ is.  Perhaps you mean to relate the sign of $\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}$ to the sign of $V$ or to the sign of $F$?  Could you be more specific than "make a statement about the sign of $\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}$"?

Comment: Also, as for your question in your post about taking the derivative of $V$ with respect to $G$ -- you should be able to do what you're suggesting.  You just have to be careful about what you're holding constant with each partial derivative.  This link may help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule

Comment: Thanks for these hints. Indeed $G$ should represent a general (continuously differentiable) function. The triple product rule hint is helpful though!